# Checking for predefined String value Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I am trying to validate my form Data using Hibernate Validator in my Spring MVC application.
I have a requirement where i need to check user input for predefined values which will not be allowed in the system.

for e.g if the value of firstName field is firstName, i want to fail the validation and tell user that this value is not allowed.

Can any one tell me how this can be achieved using hibernate validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom validator that implements `ConstraintValidator`. 
Please read this link:
[Hibernate validator](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `@Pattern` annotation on top of your field declaration. With this annotation you need to specify the java regex pattern that will match with the value input by user and if it fails you can show the proper validation message to the user in jsp.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, but @Pattern cannot work with integer , e.g. `@Pattern(regexp="^[79]$") private int location;` in this case it will throw exception `javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'location'`

Comment: and if want to know how to support integer, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772748/javax-validation-unexpectedtypeexception-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type/34703165#34703165